# How to manage an instance with a specific lifetime

Tags: xamarin.forms, unity-container, prism

I have two screens which need to manage a list of items. The user can navigate from 1st screen to 2nd screen.

When user navigates back from 1st screen, the list of items needs to be saved to a store.

The way I was thinking to do it having a service holding the collection which gets injected in the view-models. 
But the service instance must be released once user navigates back from 1st screen:

```
// somewhere, maybe in Application:
LifetimeManager = new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager();
Container.RegisterType<Service>(lifetimeManager);

class FirstPage()
{
   ContainerControlledLifetimeManager _lifetimeManager;

   public FirstPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   void OnDisappearing()
   {
       LifetimeManager.RemoveValue();
   }
}
```

But this seems awkward, there has to be a better way to do this...

I see there's a `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager` which seems it's what I need, but it would still require for `FirstPage` instance to get the instance of the manager and call `RemoveValue`. Or, I would call `GC.Collect` on `OnDisappearing` to make sure the GC collects the instance of the service, and `ExternallyControlledLifetimeManager` will recreate it next time it needs to be injected in the `FirstPageViewModel`. But calling `GC.Collect` seems wrong too...

Comment: The way you are trying to use a service makes no sense.   Why do you need a service to be the same when navigating to a view, but when navigating back it needs to be different? I think you need to rethink the function of your service.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The 1st screen creates a list of items in memory which the 2nd screen needs to use too. Once the user navigates back from the 1st screen, the list must be stored in repository. I thought the service is a good way to share the list between the screen view-models, and I don't know the correct way it should work with DI. Not sure, but I think the list is like a session which the 1st view-model creates and then it must be used by the 2nd one too.

Comment: Instead of a service, is it better to share a child view-model instance between the two screen view-models? But I still don't know how to do this with DI.

Comment: Or maybe have just one big view-model shared across the screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you should be passing your data to your views via navigation parameters.  Then each page can handle the parameters differently.  Keep it simple.

```
var p = new NavigationParameters();
p.Add("items", MyListOfItems);
_regionManager.RequestNavigate("MyView", p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `Service` in another service whose job is to provide the current instance of `Service`.

```
interface IServiceProvider
{
    Service CurrentInstance { get; set; }
}
```

Then register this one as a singleton (`ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`) and use it in both view models. The first one sets the instance to a new one, most likely created by some `IServiceFactory`, and the second one fills the instance with data.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I updated my question in the light of the comment from Brian. It's not clear to me in your example how does it ensure that the service lives as long as the 1st screen.

Comment: The service provider is registered as singleton and thus lives as long as the app, so it keeps a service instance alive, as long as it is assigned to it. Depending on your needs, you can dispose the instance when replacing it or just leave it for garbage collection.